# Spring Controller destroy method?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jakarta-ee

Does Spring's `Controller` have any sort of destroy/cleanup method? I couldn't find anything in the JavaDocs for `Controller` and `AbstractController`. I'm looking for the equivalent of `javax.servlet.Servlet`'s `destroy()` method.

The reason for this is that I'm starting a thread in my Spring controller. I want the thread to terminate whenever the controller is taken out of server (such as when the container is shutdown).

Comment: This isn't an "answer", but you probably don't really want to be starting a thread within a controller... sounds messy and like a break of the abstraction layers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the regular spring lifecycle methods. Because all Spring Controllers are Spring beans they will follow the regular lifecycle.

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that starting a thread in a controller is a good idea.  That's not what they're for, IMO.